# US taxes - which is better for capital gains, short term loss carryover or long term loss carryover?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, capital-loss

Is one carryover more valuable than the other or are they equally valuable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you have both short-term and long-term gains next year, and their total is more than the loss carryforward(s),** then

- a short-term loss carryforward is taken first against the short-term gain, and the remainder if any against the long-term gain
- a long-term loss carryforward is taken first against the long-term gain, and the remainder if any against the short-term gain

Since (uncancelled) short-term gain is taxed at ordinary income rates while long-term gain is taxed at lower rates, if you can't cancel both, **it is more advantageous to have the short-term carryforward** cancel at least some of the short-term gain.

In other situations there is no difference.